# localization of dictionary values in python

Tags: python, django, dictionary

I have a dictionary and function inside translation.py which i am calling from views.py .

Translation.py :-

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext
english_strings = {
                    "key1" :
                         {
                           "key2":ugettext("val1"),
                           "key3":ugettext("val2"),
                           "key4":ugettext("val3"),
                           .
                           .
                         }

                  }

def get_string():
    return english_strings
```

Where all keys and val's are valid strings. I am trying for localization. All val's needs to be localized. So I need to call 'ugettext' on all val's.
In above case 'django-admin.py makemessages -a' command automatically adds val's to 'locale/de/LC_MESSAGES/django.po' and its working properly.

But i don't want to write ugettext inside dictionary(before each val). Instead..

```
def get_string():
    temp = {}
    for key,val in english_strings.items():
        for k, v in val.items():
            temp[k] = ugettext(v)
    return temp
```

this is what i am trying. But in second case "django-admin.py makemessages -a" not adding val's to 'locale/de/LC_MESSAGES/django.po'. So it is not working. But function is returning key value pairs. Any suggestions would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think what you want is possible. `makemessages` does not execute your Python code, so there is no way for it to know you wrapped a value in `ugettext` later on.
There is a convention to use a `_` as a shorthand for `ugettext`, this may partially mitigate your problem (if the problem is you think wrapping every directory value in `uggettext` is too explicit). You would import `from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _` and then write `_("val1")` instead of `ugettext("val1")`.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable suggestion, the problem might be "makemessages doesn't execute Python code". Yes, i am using '_' instead of ugettext to have tidy code. Thank you.